# If $L/K$ is algebraic, is $L$ a subfield of some algebraic closure $\bar K$ of $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $L/K$ be a field extension. Is $L$ a subfield of some algebraic closure $\bar K$ of $K$?

Comment: If you believe Zorn's lemma....

Comment: This is the case if and only if $L/K$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 3):

Take an algebraic closure $F$ of $L$. I contend that $F$ is an algebraic closure of $K$.

Indeed, it is algebraically closed by assumption; if $x\in F$, then $x$ is algebraic over $L$, hence also over $K$.